# How to put multiple views in Text Input layout

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XMmg.png)

I want to make this three views in the Text Input layout in android native

I make it with linear layout but i want to convert it to Text Input Layout

`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="21dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border_layout"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_16sdp">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_110sdp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textInputEditText"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/key_edit"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_85sdp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center|start"
        android:text="+20"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="18dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textInputEditText"
        android:layout_width="304dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: you maybe looking for this [CountryCodePhonePicker](https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject)

Answer (score 0):

This time i tried and you can achieve what you want with code below:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="12dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner"
                    android:layout_width="110dp"
                    android:layout_height="56dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textInputEditText"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/key_edit"
                    android:layout_width="85dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center|start"
                    android:text="+971"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/textInputEditText"
                    android:layout_width="304dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:hint="Phone Number"
                    tools:text="56515"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:text="We will use this to verify your account" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: the icon is spinner and there is also a textview next it for the country code

Comment: I edited the answer, check that out if it can deliver what you need.